# Lasagne use image inputs as the initial hidden state of a LSTMLayer

Tags: deep-learning, theano, lasagne, theano-cuda

I am doing a project on image captioning. I want to set a batch of image features with shape=(batch_size, 512) as the initial hidden state of a LSTMLayer in Lasagne (theano). The sequence input to the LSTMLayer is a batch of text sequence with shape=(batch_size, max_sequence_length, 512). I notice that LSTMLayer in lasagne has a hid_init parameter. Does anyone know how to use it for LSTMLayer in Lasagne? Do I need to implement a custom LSTMLayer by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to set h_0 parameter, because h_0 uses c0 (see this [enter link description here](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) and write down connections from h0 to c0), so, you have to set only c0 parameter:

```
decoder = LSTMLayer(l_word_embeddings,
                num_units=LSTM_UNITS,
                cell_init=your_image_features_layer_512_shape, #this is c0
                mask_input=l_mask)
```

You can set c0 as Layer or as other arrays (see lasagne LSTM doc [enter link description here](http://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/layers/recurrent.html)).

Ready to discuss further.